# what is the default value for mapred.tasktracker.tasks.maximum in hadoop configuration

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

i found this configuration name in the link 
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces

However when i tried to search the hadoop documentation i am finding the configuration name as

```
 mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum   default value 2
 mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum      default value 2
```

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/mapred-default.html
however i am not able to find mapred.tasktracker.tasks.maximum ? please suggest if am missing some obvious understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first [link](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces) explains how many mappers (just an indication) and reducers you should set for your MapReduce job, so that you can achieve better load balancing.

The second thing that you mention is how many map tasks and reduce tasks can run at the same time in each node. In http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/mapred-default.html these configurations appear as:

```
mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum         2  
mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum      2
```

If you want to change them, then you should change the file `{$HADOOP_HOME}/conf/mapred-site.xml`, where `${HADOOP_HOME}` is the path of hadoop.

For example, if you determine that you want 8 reducers (this can be done by setting `conf.setNumReduceTasks(8);` in your code) and you keep these default values, assuming that you have 2 nodes in the cluster, each node will run 2 map tasks at the beginning, so, in overall, 2x2 = 4 map tasks will be running in your cluster. When any of these map tasks finishes, the node will run the next map task in the queue. At any point, 4 map tasks (maximum) will be running in your cluster.

**EDIT:** I found the mistake. In the first link it says:

`The right number of reduces seems to be 0.95 or 1.75 * (nodes * mapred.tasktracker.tasks.maximum).`

It should be:

`The right number of reduces seems to be 0.95 or 1.75 * (nodes * mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum).`

Comment: That statement is confusing... what is `0.95` or `1.75`? A setting that you can change?

Comment: This is a formula to calculate the number of reducers. You can pick this number to be anything you want, but the suggested values in the link provided by the OP is either `0.95` or `1.75` `* (nodes * mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum)`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was under the impression that it influences the default count, so was expecting to be a setting.

Comment: Could you please clarify this, if I have 4 hosts in my cluster each with 8 CPUs, does it mean that I should set mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum=8 or mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum=1.75 * 4 * 8=56 to maximize number of mappers?

Comment: `map.tasks.maximum` are per machine, so the maximum you can set is indeed 8. I would advise you to set it to a lower value though (eg. 6), but it also depends on how much heap you allocate to each map task, as the total should not exceed the memory of the machine.

Comment: (1.75 * 4 * `reduce.tasks.maximum`) is about the total number of reducers, when `reduce.tasks.maximum` can run at the same time at each machine